# Django admin, using easy_thumbnails show thumbnail next to uploaded image

Tags: django, django-admin

I've been struggling for a while now to show an uploaded image with a thumbnail in the django admin.

I'm using easy_thumbnails, so ideally I'd like to use that, but more than anything, could anyone paste a simple snippet showing everything required to do this.  I know there are SO posts about this as well as a number of django snippets but I still can't seem to make enough sense out of any of them to be able to accomplish this.

Currently in my model I have:

```
#model.py
main_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', null=True, blank=True)
```

How can I go from here, to showing the thumbnail next to the image?

Thanks in anticipation,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out eventually ;)

```
#in model.py
class Blog(models.Model):
    main_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', null=True, blank=True)

    def image_thumb(self):
        return '<img src="/media/%s" width="100" height="100" />' % (self.main_image)
    image_thumb.allow_tags = True

#in admin.py
class BlogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = (('main_image', 'image_thumb'))

     readonly_fields = ('image_thumb',)

admin.site.register(Blog, BlogAdmin)
```